# How to use generics as a parameter in kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, generics, lambda

I was trying to understand how to create a thread safe singleton in kotlin,but while going through the answer I stumbled upon another query related to generics and lambdas.
Here is the mindorks code
[Mindorks code](https://blog.mindorks.com/how-to-create-a-singleton-class-in-kotlin/#:%7E:text=In%20lazy%20initialization%2C%20we%20use,synchronization%20and%20double%2Dchecked%20locking.)

The code says

```
open class SingletonHolder<out T: Any, in A>(creator: (A) -> T) {
private var creator: ((A) -> T)? = creator
@Volatile private var instance: T? = null

fun getInstance(arg: A): T {
    val checkInstance = instance
    if (checkInstance != null) {
        return checkInstance
    }

    return synchronized(this) {
        val checkInstanceAgain = instance
        if (checkInstanceAgain != null) {
            checkInstanceAgain
        } else {
            val created = creator!!(arg)
            instance = created
            creator = null
            created
        }
    }
}
```

}
So I want to understand how this line is working `(creator: (A) -> T)` as a param, and then again
in the code under synchronized method `val created = creator!!(arg)`
Can someone please help me to destruct this and help me understand, or maybe compare this with reference to a java code ? so that I understand it better.

Thanks,

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? I don't really understand your confusion. I think generics has maybe nothing to do with it and you simply don't understand the notation of `(Class) -> OtherClass` maybe?

Comment: `(A) -> T` is a function receiving `A` and returning `T`, so this is similar to Java: `Function<A, T>`. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @Ivo specially this part creator: (A) -> T like how are they passing this a s a param and then using it  lik eval created = creator!!(arg) and then in the code YourManager.getInstance(context).doSomething(). So how all of this is working underneath ?

Comment: @broot but then how does it works in the code like val created = creator!!(arg) ? and then the actual call  YourManager.getInstance(context).doSomething( , can you please connect these and explain ?

Comment: `(A) -> T` is the type of a function.  And it's stored in `creator`. `creator(arg)` simply calls it, but since the `creator` variable is nullable `!!` is added to indicate that you are sure it's not null

Comment: @ivo but lets say I want to write a simple addition function like take a param in as A, and return it out as V with adding 1 to it, so can you please tell how the same thing will work here ? so there I need to do creator!!(arg + 1) ? or rather can you tell a code for simple addition in the above manner ?

Comment: @Pritish if you want for example A as Int and B as Double and add 1 to the int before changing it to double you could create a `SingletonHolder` like this for example: `val mySingletonHolder = SingletonHolder { a : Int -> (a + 1).toDouble() }`

Comment: Cool thanks , let me try your code practically and try to understand.

Comment: BTW, if you don't need your singleton to be a separate subclass/`object` and you just need a singleton variable, then Kotlin already provides such util: `val singleton by lazy {  /* calculateValue */ }`.

Comment: @broot yes I agree that is the part of actually writing the singleton , but since I stumbled upon this code and could not figure out why it is written this way, and how it is exactly working , like maybe I may need it somewhere else as well.